# Add attribute to a header element via makeEnvelope

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I have an ingest flow in DHF5, using JavaScript, that calls `makeEnvelope()` to actually construct the XML envelope. The headers parameter is an object that gets turned into name/value pairs. Is there any way to include an attribute on one of those headers?

Eventually, I'd like something like this:

```
let headers={};
headers["firstAttribute"] = foo;
datahub.flow.flowUtils.makeEnvelope(content, headers, triples, "xml");

<envelope xmlns="http://marklogic.com/entity-services">
  <headers>
    <firstHeader xmlns="">foo</firstHeader >
    <secondHeader xmlns="" myattribute="xyz">bar</secondHeader>
  </headers>
  [...]
</envelope>
```

I just don't see any way to create `secondHeader` with `myattribute`.

Answer (score 0):

You could send them in XML format instead of as a JSON object with key/value.

This way, using a [`NodeBuilder`](https://docs.marklogic.com/js/NodeBuilder) to construct the XML:

```
let triples = null;
let content = {};
let builder = new NodeBuilder();
builder.startElement("headers");

builder.startElement("firstHeader");
builder.addText("foo");
builder.endElement();

builder.startElement("secondHeader");
builder.addAttribute("myAttribute", "xyz");
builder.addText("bar");
builder.endElement();
builder.endElement();

let headers = builder.toNode();

makeEnvelope(content, headers, triples, "xml");
```

Or this way (kind of gross, but shorter and easier), parsing a string into XML using [`xmp.unquote()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.unquote):

```
let triples = null;
let content = {};

let headers = xdmp.unquote('<headers><firstHeader xmlns="">foo</firstHeader><secondHeader myAttribute="xyz" xmlns="">bar</secondHeader></headers>');

makeEnvelope(content, headers, triples, "xml");
```